# Is there a way to put geotif as input data in a tensor flow or keras in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, geotiff

I would like to use geotif image as input data in a tensor flow or keras.

I know that tensorflow does not support tif.

So I tried using gdal to make it into a raster image, but it failed.

Please let me know if there is a way to put geotif in tensorflow or keras in python.

Comment: TIFF is just a raster image format, you just need to load it and give it as input. If you have problems you have to be specific with them in your question.

Comment: Not sure if you will get a distorted image, but you could try Pillow, or cv2 for instance, instead of gdal.

Comment: pixesl dtype is float32  so using gdal get ratser images in numpy array. but i want to convolution images detection. but dtype error is occur.

Comment: also each of pixels info is important so i can't convert any other type images.